# Grouping data by multiple criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, consolidation

I think I have a quick question, but I didn't find a way to google it in simple words.

I've got a raw dataset like this:

```
 Number of account     Value
      123               100
      456               300
      789               400
      910               100
      674               250
```

And I've got a methodological table to consolidate this raw data into something useful. It looks like:

```
 Variable              Number of account
    "a"                  123, 456, 910
    "b"                    789,674
```

So, in the end I would like to get a table like this:

```
 Variable              Number of account
    "a"                  Sum of values for(123, 456, 910)
    "b"                  Sum of values for(789,674)
```

My initial idea is to do something like: *For each row in methodological table, For each Number of account in methodological table, Sum values in raw data*.

Two questions:

1. What is the best way to consolidate it?
2. What if in methodological table number of accounts are comma-delimited strings? ("123,456,910"). Can I store multiple numbers in one cell in pandas DataFrame

Comment: whats the logic for grouoping `123, 456, 910` and `789, 674` ?

Comment: These are just account numbers (i.e. reference numbers). Let's say "a" stands for "Total loans to households from a bank". 123 - loan <1 year maturity, 456 - 1-3 years maturity, 910 - 3+ years maturity. And I would like to sum them all to get total loans. 
If you are talking about numbers themselves - they are just fake numbers, not to create any idea of consequence of pattern here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have data in two dataframes:

`df` is :

```
Number_of_account     Value
      123               100
      456               300
      789               400
      910               100
      674               250
```

and `table_2` is:

```
Variable              Number_of_account
    "a"                  123,456,910
    "b"                    789,674
```

First, I'll create a lookup table out of table2:

```
lookup_table = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['Variable'], row['Number_of_account'].split(','))              
                         for _, row in table_2.iterrows()]).reset_index()
lookup_table.columns = ["Number_of_account", "variable"]
lookup_table.Number_of_account = pd.to_numeric(lookup_table.Number_of_account)
```

The result is:

```
   Number_of_account variable
0                123        a
1                456        a
2                910        a
3                789        b
4                674        b
```

Then, I merge the main dataframe (`df`) with the lookup table, and use `groupby` to calculate the sum of the values.

```
df = pd.merge(df, lookup_table, on="Number_of_account")
df.groupby("variable")["Value"].sum()
```

The result is:

```
variable
a    500
b    650
```